# EditText is not working properly on Moto 360

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, moto-360

I am having trouble trying to get EditText to work on my watch.  It works on the emulator on Android Studio, when I click on the edittext field a separate screen pops up where you can place numbers. Similar UI to a calculator. When I click on the EditText field on my watch nothing happens.  I can't place any numbers, the button and spinner work.

The app takes input from the user and can convert it to other measurements.

This is the activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_grey"
android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
    app:boxedEdges="">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberr"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:hint="#"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:entries="@array/choices"></Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/con"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:text="__"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Conv" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This is the MainActivity.java

```
   package com.example.robertomejiajr.watch2;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
   import android.text.TextUtils;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Spinner;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import org.w3c.dom.Text;

   import java.text.DecimalFormat;

   import static android.widget.Toast.*;

   public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements 
   AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {






     //these are the options that are available

     //Fahrenheit to Celsius
     //Celsius to Fahrenheit

     //Inch to Centimeter
     //Centimeter to Inch
     //Feet to Centimeter
     //Centimeter to Feet
     //Feet to Mile
     //Mile to Feet
     //Mile to Kilometer
     //Kilometer to Mile

     //Pound to Gram
     //Gram to Pound

     //Ounce to Milliliter
     //Milliliter to Ounce


    // This is value for user input
     double n1;

     // This is the value for the answer for any of the formulas

      double y;

    // This will determine what option the user
    // chose for the spinner, default is first option
     int n = 0;



Spinner spinner;
EditText et1;
Button button;
TextView conn;






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    //this is for spinner
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.formulas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);




     adapter.setDropDownViewResource
     (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

      spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



       ///////////////// these are linking the EditText, TextView, Button, to 
       the variables
       et1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberr);
       conn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.con);
       button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Double num1=Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
            n1 = num1;
            conn.setText("" + n1);
            DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
            DecimalFormat df5 = new DecimalFormat(".#####");
            if (n == 0)
            {

            }
            if (n == 1)
            {
                y = ( (n1 - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0) );

                conn.setText(n1 + " °F = " + df2.format(y) + " °C");
            }
            if (n == 2)
            {
                y = (n1 * (9.0 / 5)) + 32;
                conn.setText(n1 + " °C = " + df2.format(y) + " °F");
            }
            if (n == 3)
            {
                y = (n1 * 2.54);
                conn.setText(n1 + " in = " + df2.format(y) + " cm");
            }
            if (n == 4)
            {
                y = (n1 / 2.54);
                conn.setText(n1 + " cm = " + df2.format(y) + " in");
            }
            if (n == 5)
            {
                y = (n1 * 30.48 );
                conn.setText(n1 + " ft = " + df2.format(y) + " cm");
            }
            if (n == 6)
            {
                y = (n1 / 30.48 );
                conn.setText(n1 + " cm = " + df5.format(y) + " ft");
            }
            if (n == 7)
            {
                y = (n1 / 5280.0);
                conn.setText(n1 + " ft = " + df5.format(y) + " M");
            }

            if (n == 8)
            {
                y = (n1 * 5280.0);
                conn.setText(n1 + " M = " + df2.format(y) + " ft");
            }
            if (n == 9)
            {
                y = (n1 * 1.60934);
                conn.setText(n1 + "M = " + df2.format(y) + " km");
            }
            if (n == 10)
            {
                y = (n1 / 1.60934);
                conn.setText(n1 + " km = " + df5.format(y) + " M");
            }
            if (n == 11)
            {
                y = (n1 / .00220462262 );
                conn.setText(n1 + " lb = " + df2.format(y) + " g");
            }
            if (n == 12)
            {
                y = (n1 * .00220462262 );
                conn.setText(n1 + " g = " + df5.format(y) + " lb");
            }
            if (n == 13)
            {
                y = (n1 / 0.033814);
                conn.setText(n1 + "oz = " + df2.format(y) + " ml");
            }
            if (n == 14)
            {
                y = (n1 * 0.033814);
                conn.setText(n1 + " ml = " + df5.format(y) + " oz");
            }





          }
      });
   }


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {

            String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


             if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                if (selection.equals("Pick One")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 0;
                    }

                if (selection.equals("Fahrenheit to Celsius")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(n1), 
                 LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 1;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Celsius to Fahrenheit")) {

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "hello", LENGTH_SHORT 
                 ).show();
                    n = 2;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Inch to Centimeter")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 3;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Centimeter to Inch")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 4;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Feet to Centimeter")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 5;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Centimeter to Feet")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 6;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Feet to Mile")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 7;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Mile to Feet")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 8;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Mile to Kilometer")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 9;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Kilometer to Mile")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 10;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Pound to Gram")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 11;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Gram to Pound")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 12;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Ounce to Milliliter")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 13;
                }
                if(selection.equals("Milliliter to Ounce")) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,selection, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    n = 14;
                }







            }

        }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}

}
```